# How to make an image in a table cell clickable

Tags: javascript, image, html-table, onclick, clickable

I am a beginner programmer and am struggling to figure out how to make an image clickable.

I have a set of images that I placed into a table, because that is the layout I need. The goal is to get linked to another pages once a certain image from the table is selected. 
So far this is what I have (with multiple cells):

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <a>
            <img src="img1.jpg" width="400" height="178" class="next" onclick="change('http://www.google.com')"/>
        </a>
        <div class="imgText"> Image 1 </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onclick`, why not use `href` of link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="img1.jpg" width="400" height="178" class="next" /></a>
```

Although with JavaScript, you would use `window.location`:

```
onclick="window.location = 'http://www.google.com'"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have somewhere in your code:

```
<script>
...
function change(location){
  window.location = location;
}
...
```

it should work. Also Blaster's response is very good, keep in mind to give the image border=0.
Images in  tags with the hreh attribute set get borders on some browsers.